# How do I fix error CS8803? I think it might have to do with .NET 6.0 but what do I know

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to recreate Brackey's Classes tutorial from memory (checked afterwards, of course) and I've run into an issue concerning the order/placement of a fragment. Here's the code:

```
class Wizard
{
    public static string name;
    public static string spell;
    public static float experience;
    public static int slots;

    public Wizard(string _name, string _spell)
    {
        name = _name;
        spell = _spell;
        slots = 2;
        experience = 0f;
    }

    public void CastSpell()
    {
        if (slots > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} casted {spell}.");
            slots--;
            experience += 0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} is out of spells!");    
        }

        static void Meditate() //Used static void because public didn't work for some reason?
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} meditates and regains all their spells!");
            slots = 2;
        }
    }
}
 
Wizard wizard1 = new Wizard("Wiz Name", "Spellum lazyum"); 
wizard1.CastSpell();
```

My problem lies in the placement of these last two lines. When I have them inside the Wizard class, it gives me the error `Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration`. Outside, it throws `Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations.` Am I correct in thinking that the latter might happen because of the 'removal' of the Program class in .NET 6.0? I think I have an okay understand of classes, but clearly I'm missing something. Sorry if this is a simple fix; I didn't get much sleep last night.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the last two lines. These lines are executable code. Executable code must be inside a method.

Executable code is also allowed as top-level statements with specific syntax, hence the error message, but that is not relevant to your use case.

I don't know when you want to execute those two lines of code, but you probably do, so you should move them to the correct location

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, I think. Where exactly is that correct location? Back in Brackeys' tutorial, VSC still had the Program class, so I assume that's why it worked fine. I just assumed that the code necessary for the Program class was still there, it was just no longer visible for simplicity's sake. So do I need to make a new class to execute code normally, or make a method for creating a Wizard?

Comment: Well what are you trying to do? If you are trying to copy Brackey just copy Brackey. Otherwise you will need to have an understanding of what you are trying to make your code do. There are infinite ways to get your code to compile but only a small subset of those solutions will make your code do what you want it to do. Nobody here can telepathically guess what your code is trying to do so you need to decide that yourself.

Comment: If you want to execute those two lines as a top level statement you need to move them above the first class declaration in this file

Comment: Sorry I assumed that moving those lines above the Wizard class worked, so thank you! I was trying to essentially "make a wizard character" in this context, so that involved passing `new Wizard(name, spell)`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AnimeniacSimey Don't forget to upvote and select a best answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of small problems. You want to support more than one wizard, so you probably want the fields to be instance rather than static. Your `Meditate()` is defined as a local function inside `CastSpell` which is not what you want. Your example usage code needs to be inside another class & method. Though you could place that within [top level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements).

```cs
class Wizard
{
    public string name;
    public string spell;
    public float experience;
    public int slots;

    public Wizard(string _name, string _spell)
    {
        name = _name;
        spell = _spell;
        slots = 2;
        experience = 0f;
    }

    public void CastSpell()
    {
        if (slots > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} casted {spell}.");
            slots--;
            experience += 0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{name} is out of spells!");    
        }
    }

    public void Meditate() //Used static void because public didn't work for some reason?
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{name} meditates and regains all their spells!");
        slots = 2;
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Wizard wizard1 = new Wizard("Wiz Name", "Spellum lazyum"); 
        wizard1.CastSpell();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't notice I had Meditate inside CastSpell!! Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

No. The error is not related to NET.6.0.

Code cannot exist directly within a class while being outside of methods (or field/property initializers with respect to expressions). Hence the first error message.

Code can exist as top-level statements, but as the 2nd error message tells you, any top-level statements must precede type declarations. The declaration of a class is a type declaration. Thus your top-level statements do not precede the declaration of your Wizard class, hence error.

Comment: Meditate is written totally fine. `static` is allowed in local functions. I'm not sure what youre getting at

Comment: @Nigel, oops. Yeah, i got fooled by the scrollbars of the code view. Didn't see the actual two last lines. Argh...